# I've created an Hyper-V replica Alert Script but struggling to get it alert me when an condition is met

Tags: powershell

```
$status = Get-VMReplication | Select-Object Name, State, Health, Mode, FrequencySec, PrimaryServer, ReplicaServer, ReplicaPort | ConvertTo-Html
$Company = ""
$ReplicationHealth = (Get-VMReplication)
function ReplicationHealthFailedTelegram {
    $token = (Get-Content -Path C:\temp\telegrambot\token.txt)
    $chatid = (Get-Content -Path C:\temp\telegrambot\chatid.txt)
    $Message = "Replication Failed"
    $Company = ""
    $status = Get-VMReplication | Select-Object Name, State, Health, Mode, FrequencySec, PrimaryServer, ReplicaServer, ReplicaPort | ConvertTo-Html
    & 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe' -Command { $token = (Get-Content -Path C:\temp\telegrambot\token.txt);$chatid = (Get-Content -Path C:\temp\telegrambot\chatid.txt); $status = Get-VMReplication | Select-Object Name, State, Health, Mode, FrequencySec, PrimaryServer, ReplicaServer, ReplicaPort | ConvertTo-Html;$Message = "Replication Failed";$Company = "Howard Matthews Partnership - Harrogate";Send-TelegramTextMessage -BotToken $token -ChatID $chatid -Message $Company $Message}
    }
function EmailAlert {
    $User = "alert@domain.co.uk"
    $File = (Get-Content C:\Temp\pw.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString)
    $MyCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
    -ArgumentList $User, $File

            $To = "domain.co.uk"
            $from = "domain.co.uk"
            $EmailSubject = "Hyper-V Replication Error $Company"
            $smtp = "auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk"
            $DefaultMessage="
                <p>Dear Help,</p>
                <p>Replication has failed for $Company </p>
                <p>$status</p>
                <p>The Robot Checker .<br><br>
                </p>"

            $MailMessage = @{
                    To = $To
                    From = $from
                    # BCC = $Bcc
                    Subject = $EmailSubject
                    Body = $DefaultMessage
                    priority = "High"
                    Smtpserver = $smtp
                    Credential = $MyCredential
                    ErrorAction = "SilentlyContinue" 
                }

            Send-MailMessage @MailMessage -bodyashtml
}

if ($ReplicationHealth.health) {
    "Critical","Warning"
    EmailAlert
    ReplicationHealthFailedTelegram
} else {
    $null
}
```

The Email sends but it regardless if the status of the replication is normal, warning or critical. How would I go by adding the logic of getting to send me an email when that health status is Critical or Warning and not send me an email when it's normal.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit doesn't do what you think it should

```
if ($ReplicationHealth.health) {
    "Critical","Warning"
    EmailAlert
    ReplicationHealthFailedTelegram
} else {
    $null
}
```

With your if you are basically asking; "is $ReplicationHealth.Health a thing?" rather than checking for the value "of the thing", and the answer will always be yes in this case assuming nothing went wrong running `Get-VMReplication`.

A different example to demonstrate what I mean could be something like the following

```
if($(Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:windir\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe").Extension) { "Yup, .Extension is a thing" } else { "Nah, it's not!" }
if($(Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:windir\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe").Extension -eq ".exe") { "Yup, .Extension is a thing and its value is `'.exe`'" } else { "Nah, it's not!" }
```

In order to fix your if, you could try something like

```
if($ReplicationHealth.Health -eq "Critical" -or $ReplicationHealth.Health -eq "Warning") {
    EmailAlert
    ReplicationHealthFailedTelegram
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I needed! You increased my Powershell foo!